# Send single object from model in method within CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm basically formatting urls before sending my object to the view to loop through (with a `foreach()` on `$submissions`. The problem I'm having is that parse_url() takes a single index and not an entire array object.

I've got this method in my SubmissionsController:

```
public function newest() {        
    $submissions = $this->Submission->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Submission.approved' => '1'),
        'order' => 'Submission.created DESC'
            ));

    $this->set('submissions', $submissions);
    $this->set('sourceShortUrl', AppController::shortSource($submissions));
}
```

In my AppController I've got this method which returns the formatted url:

```
protected function shortSource($source) {
    return $sourceShortUrl = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($source, PHP_URL_HOST));
}
```

This works for single entries, but parse_url can't take arrays, so is there a way in the controller to send the index of the object? E.g. $submissions['Submission']['source'] before I loop through it in the view?

My alternative was to do something like this in my `shortSource($source)` method:

```
if (is_array($source)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($source); $i++) {
        return $sourceShortUrl = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($source[$i]['Submission']['source'], PHP_URL_HOST));
    }
}
```

But that's just returning the first (obviously). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Check for an array. If it's an array, call it recursively for each item in the array.

```
/**
* shortSource
*
* Returns an array of URLs with the www. removed from the front of the domain name.
* 
* @param mixed $source Either a string or array
* @return mixed $sourceShortUrl An array of URLs or a single string
*/
protected function shortSource($source) {
    if (is_array($source)) {
        foreach ($source as $url) {
            $sourceShortUrl[] = $this->shortSource($url);
        }
    } else {
        $sourceShortUrl = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($source, PHP_URL_HOST));
    }
    return $sourceShortUrl;
}
```

In this recursive function, it will parse a single string or an array of strings.

```
// in the view
if (is_array($sourceShortUrl)) {
    foreach ($sourceShortUrl as $url) {
        // view specific code for URL here
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks man! I ended up modifying a little bit and now I'm just calling it within the view as `SubmissionsController::shortSource($submission['Submission']['source'])` so it doesn't need to be in the AppController and be protected.

Comment: @bob: although it shouldnt be in the controller in the first place. seems more like a library function to me...

Comment: Depends on the architecture. If it needs to be used multiple places, then yes. Or if it is used on all URL fields it would be even better as a behavior. But if it applies only to the URLs in this controller, it is better to keep it in the controller/model here to keep the code better organized.